# What is the origin of the visions of Walt, that Shannon experiences?

Tags: lost

After the raft burns, Shannon sees twice Walt. My first thought would be that this would be the Man In Black, trying to get her killed, but it has been established that he can only morph into people that have died, and Walt is alive.

So what is the origin of these visions?

Answer (score 1):

You're right regarding the [Man In Black](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Monster):

> In this form he could manifest as deceased individuals, most
>   frequently as his former body.

That means that these were visions. Their origin wasn't explained.

I think the most logical theory is: since we know that Walt had paranormal abilities, it can be assumed that he was telepathically connecting with Shannon and causing the visions ([apparently](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Walt#Days_44.E2.80.9367_.28Season_2.29) his message was "Push the button. Don't push the button. Bad.").

You can also check fan theories on Lostpedia regarding [the vision](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Shannon_Rutherford/Theories) and [Walt](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Walt_Lloyd/Theories).

Comment: Is there any proof of evidence that points towards being Walt's magical powers?

Comment: @Dbugger There is none, but the origin of the visions wasn't explained, so we can only speculate. My answer is also a speculation, the one that seems the most logical to me.

Comment: @Dbugger I've edited my answer to make what I stated in my previous comment more clear.